# Months ago in ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I can't figure out a way (using class definitions) to get months ago. Seconds, days, and minutes are all fine because they're always constants. However since months isn't always constant, i need to know a way for ruby to know how many days are in the current month.

Comment: Note, the number of seconds in a day is not constant (daylight savings)

Comment: There's also leap seconds if we want to be really pedantic, which might be replaced with leap hours. Neither of which should be confused with leap frogs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Answer (score 9):

If your application uses ActiveSupport (e.g. a Rails application), you can use

```
3.months.ago
```

to get the current date less 3 months.

Comment: Without ActiveSupport you can use Date.today << 3.

Comment: The shift operator is awesome! Thanks for pointing that one out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know how many days there were in between two dates, say today and the same day number of the last month you can do this:

```
(Date.today - Date.today.prev_month).to_i
```

This would give you the number of days in the previous month. If you want to know the number of days for the current month you can instead do:

```
(Date.today.next_month - Date.today).to_i
```

Comment: This is wrong. The first case fails when today is 31st of March, for example. This will return 31, however in February (which is prevuios month to March) can never be more than 29 days.

<code><pre>irb(main):013:0> today = Date.parse '2011-03-31'
=> #<Date: 2011-03-31 (4911303/2,0,2299161)>
irb(main):014:0> (today - today.prev_month).to_i
=> 31</pre></code>

Comment: Very true, I didn't realize that Date#prev_month would return the last day of the previous month for every day with a number larger than the number of the last day of the previous month (e.g. for March 31, 30, 29 and 28 #prev_month returns Feb 28.

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you're looking for?  [DaysIn(MonthNum)](http://www.geekpedia.com/code31_Get-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-using-Ruby.html)

**EDIT 2019-01-20 (for historical purposes)**

In the comments, it was reported the link was broken.  Thanks to the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160415234512/http://www.geekpedia.com/code31_Get-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-using-Ruby.html), here's the original article.

The code block suggested there was:

```
def DaysIn(MonthNum)
   (Date.new(Time.now.year,12,31).to_date<<(12-MonthNum)).day
end
```

However, as another reader pointed out -- it appears that the desired content was probably months *ago*, rather than number of days in month.

This question answered the latter part of the question: "i need to know a way for ruby to know *how many days are in the current month*."

Comment: I *think* what he's looking for (by how he says "Months ago") is more like Oracles `months_between` function which will return the numbers of months (as a decimal) between two date values. It takes into account the different lengths of months. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/months_between.php

Comment: The link is broken!